# Telecommunication Customer churn Dataset

Tags: data-request, telecom

I am looking for a dataset for Customer churn prediction in telecom. I looked around but couldn't find any relevant dataset to download. Following are some of the features I am looking in the dataset:

- Personal information: the date of activate, churn date...
- Traffic details: Average of monthly calls number, daily average of calls minute...
- Billing data: payment type, mean of monthly revenues, Delays in the payment of the bill...
- Complaints information: number of register a complaint, number of repairs...

Comment: An example of cable complaints: http://catalog.data.gov/dataset/cable-complaints-90266 and http://www.bbb.org/washington-dc-eastern-pa/business-reviews/television-cable-catv-and-satellite/comcast-corporation-in-philadelphia-pa-80003221 . But the other three items don't get published.

Comment: I work a lot with telco data, and I've got the same impression: I've never seen anything publicly available on the first three items.

Comment: Hi, Have you got the data now?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of data is highly private, I think you can contact the telco company for this kind of data.

Currently, there are about 2 datasets which are free, one is the [KDD-CUP 2009 dataset from Orange Company](http://www.kdd.org/kdd-cup/view/kdd-cup-2009/Data) and another one is [the one from UCI](http://www.sgi.com/tech/mlc/db/).

Comment: @JanDoggen please check these links!